# "Click Anywhere" Page before Real Page shows

Tags: html

I want to make a page where background music autoplays. But modern browser doesn't allow music to autoplay without user haven't done anything in the webpage. So I want to make a click anywhere page, where the real page isnt showing up yet, when they click, the real page shows and the music starts playing

I haven't tried anything, cuz Im not very good at html, I mainly code javascript

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't need to create an extra "click anywhere" page. Autoplay is blocked in some browsers (ex. Chrome 67+) but there is a workaround. You mainly code in Javascript so you will be able to do it.

Create an extra `iframe` element with your music as src attribute, make it unvisible etc.
Then, using Javascript, check if your browser blocks autoplay or not. If not, remove extra iframe.

Comment: can iframe make the music looped?

Comment: @JerBlox don't think so, cuz Chrome blocks autoplay, so it's better than nothing. Use <audio> for the other browsers, I will be looped then.

Comment: I made a click anywhere overlay instead, but thanks for your help